# "No metadata was found for conda" when trying to activate Anaconda environment

Tags: linux, package, anaconda

I'm getting the following error when I try `conda activate <environment>` or any `conda` command, whether it's clean or anything else.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 563, in from_name
    return next(cls.discover(name=name))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/conda", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('conda==23.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'conda')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/conda", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 981, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 565, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for conda
```

I'm unsure as to why this is showing up. I've tried to uninstall and install in Arch, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after updating arch today.

It seems I was using aur/python-conda which has been flagged as out of date (2023-05-11). Might have been the cause of the error.

For me it was coming up when opening RStudio & disappeared after reinstalling miniconda via `reticulate::install_miniconda()`. For now I've also changed away from aur/python-conda to a different aur conda package.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.11.3-2 (default for installing the `python` package) and I see that it's not a dependency on the `python-conda` AUR. I'm still trying to diagnose it. But the `python` package is also flagged as out-of-date on AUR too.

Comment: I have Manjaro, got the same problem,
and, yes, reinstallation of python-conda via pamac helped